# OpenVPN network asks for password

Tags: networking, ubuntu, openvpn

I setup a vpn connection under user_A and it works just fine (I used network-manager-openvpn-gnome to setup this connection).

Now I added another user into my system (Ubuntu 16.04) -- user_B. I logged in under user_B's account and I created another (separated) vpn connection in this user_B's profile.

Now (still under user_B's account) I want to connect to the newly created user_B's vpn connection and Ubuntu asks for root password for some reason. I cancel the password prompt (press Esc), it asks again, I cancel it again and it connects (and works).

Why Ubuntu asks for this password, when it does not need it?

Comment: Did you create the new user under `Standard` account?

Comment: I used GUI to create the account and if you ask if I set "administrator" mode to user_B then no, user_B is a standard account

Comment: I guess that is the reason why it asks for password, I am not sure though. Try creating an `Administrator` user to check.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the reason the system asks for the admin password is because you are starting the VPN for all users (this is the default on Gnome) you would want to untick that option on the VPN config, this way your user can start the VPN without admin rights. This also explains why it still works when you cancel, as you still get the VPN, but no one else gets it (I assume)